# PHP Prepared-Statement: binding variable parameters

Tags: php, database, api, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a problem with a varchar in my database that only displays 0 instead of the in the past written text. I have a URL that contains some parameters like nickname, points or the difficulty of the game.

`localhost/api.php?nickname=test&points=5&difficulty=3`

These parameters gets an api (see the code below) and write them into the database.

```
<?php
$nickname = $_GET['nickname'];
$points = $_GET['points'];
$difficulty = $_GET['difficulty'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "games", "123", "tictactoe");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Error");
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
$sql ="insert into highscores (nickname, points, difficulty) values (?, ?, ?)";
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))) {
    die("Error");
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
if (!$stmt->bind_param("isi", $nickname, $points, $difficulty)) {
    die("Error");
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    die("Error");
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

But my problem is: Why does all varchars in the database have the value `0` if the api bind the parameters with a String that is like `"test"` ?

```
id  nickname  points  difficulty
1      0        5         3
2      0        5         3
3      0        5         3
4      0        5         3
5      0        5         3
6      0        5         3
7      0        5         3
```

The database structure:

```
Column       Type         Null     Standard   Comments
id          int(11)       No         
nickname    varchar(20)   No             
points      int(11)       No         
difficulty  tinyint(4)    No
```

I hope you can understand my problem and can help me :)

Comment: Why are you using `isi` in `bind_param`? From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php): _"i  corresponding variable has type integer"_. You just 'told' `mysqli` that you wanted to send an integer for `nickname`...

Comment: Should be `sii`, not `isi`.  You're specifying the nickname is an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding is inverted.

```
$stmt->bind_param("isi", $nickname, $points, $difficulty)
```

says that `$nickname` and `$difficulty` are integers. Your DB has `nickname` as `varchar` though.

It should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sii", $nickname, $points, $difficulty)
```

You can see it documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

```
Character   Description
i           corresponding variable has type integer
d           corresponding variable has type double
s           corresponding variable has type string
b           corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

Comment: Yea, or unclear what it did. Hopefully it being written out will help.

Comment: Thank your for the solution. This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the bind_parm. You are using "i" which is for integer. You must use "s" which is what you need.

```
i   corresponding variable has type integer
d   corresponding variable has type double
s   corresponding variable has type string
b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

Comment: Thank your for the documentation. This helped me much for other usage.